# Chrome rendering issue?

Tags: bug, status-completed, google-chrome

Seem to have a lot of whitespace on the https://stackoverflow.com/questions link using chrome?

Chrome version is 3.0.195.27

http://tinypic.com/r/2r7osb7/4

(Note, zoom (<kbd>CTRL-Middle Mouse Scroll</kbd>), then unzoom removes this whitespace)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that all the time. In fact, this was asked before, but declined as "status-norepro".  At least you thought to take a screenshot ;)

Personally, I think the problem has to do with ignored tags, in that Chrome is not correctly reclaiming the space left over from questions hidden for having ignored tags.  To test this, you could try switching your "hide ignored tags" option for a while and seeing if the issue goes away.

Comment: yes, it's a peculiarity of Chrome / WebKit having to do with hidden tags in the user preferences.

Answer (score 4):

Chrome 5.0, which was just released, *finally* fixes this. PRAISE THE LORD AND PASS THE AMMO.