# Questions with ignored tags break the layout

Tags: bug, status-completed, ignored-tags, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Hide ignored tags” should retrieve more questions to fill up the page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9787/hide-ignored-tags-should-retrieve-more-questions-to-fill-up-the-page)

When I browse the full [list of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest), many are hidden thanks to ignored tags (and the pref to completely hide them). The problem is, this breaks the page layout. There are several screenfuls of whitespace to scroll through between the last question and the navigation links to the next page. Happens with chromium 4, but not firefox.

**Edit**: I found [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27759/chrome-rendering-issue), if I Ctrl + Ctrl - the whitespace disappears. Could be a chromium layout bug, or could be event handlers being ordered slightly differently.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Chromium 4.0.291 Linux x64. And hidden questions are greyed out, not replaced by whitespace.

Comment: That's a known issue. They are filtered on the client side. Status-bydesign, I guess. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9787/hide-ignored-tags-should-retrieve-more-questions-to-fill-up-the-page

Comment: @Macha: there's a pref for completely hiding
@John: I don't mind the client side filtering, but it doesn't work as well in chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dupe is not in fact a dupe.

In Chrome, for some reason, the hidden `<div>`s (when you have "hide unanswered questions" checked in your profile) do *not* collapse as they do in Firefox, Safari, IE8, and Opera.

So you end up with a ton of empty whitespace where the hidden questions were...

edit: Chrome 5.0 which was just released FINALLY fixes this. Friggin' finally.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if chromium or stackoverflow did it, but I don't have that problem anymore.
So thanks.